# CABasicAnimation comleted immediately after CALayer "setFrame", why?

Tags: objective-c, animation, calayer

```
-(void)startAnimationWithTime:(CGFloat)animationTime
                    fromPoint:(CGPoint)fromPoint
                      toPoint:(CGPoint)toPoint
                   Completion:(SYBDanmakuAnimationCompletion)completion
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        completion(YES);
    }];
    CABasicAnimation *mover = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [mover setDuration:animationTime];
    [mover setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:fromPoint]];
    [mover setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPoint]];
    [self addAnimation:mover forKey:@"move"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This is the code of myLayer ,when I change the frame of its superLayer , this animation will complete immediately, who can tell me why? I want it to work correctly.

Comment: why have you disabled the animations using CATransaction disableActions ?

Comment: I do not need the implicit animation of CALayer here, so I make it disabled.

Comment: what does that actually mean ? If you disableActions it wont animate you values from initial to final state. Since, you are adding animation to the layer, it is no more an implicit animation.

Comment: Remove the CATransaction call and you will have animation explicitly called with your preferences.

Comment: Oh, I see. But it doesn't matter in my project , the damaku's initial and final state are outside of screen.